# Detect either _self or _blank, parse URL in href to function and window.open(URL, '_self') or window.open(URL, '_blank')

Tags: jquery, function, href

I had spent the past 2 days fixing malfunction `href=""` links after inserting certain jQuery `DIV`s scroller with scrollbar.

I have `href=""` links in these DIVs, clicked on them but browser not doing anything, whether they are `_self` or `_blank`.

Hence, the hack via `window.open()`, resulting either `window.open(URL, '_self')` or `window.open(URL, '_blank')`.

I would like to create a jQuery function, via `.class` as selector, detect whether the original `href=""` is of target `_self` or `_blank`, and parse the URL from href to respective if else in the function and make the links work.

to clear things up:

conventional <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"> or <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_self"> doesn't work after applying above said jQuery content scroller.

Hence, I worked around using <a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_blank');">

However, I was trying to do this via a jQuery function instead doing inline everytime. This function is capable to detect whether target is _blank or _self, capture the URL and return back using window.open() with _blank or _self respectively.

Comment: Please show us some code.. I don't understand exactly if your link has empty hrefs? is that correct?

Comment: example:

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_self">

above conventional method doesn't work, browsers just not responding to the links.

Hence, I found a workaround, using:

<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_blank');>
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com/', '_self');

Instead to inline trigger window.open, I would love to create a jQuery function to capture href="url" and target="value" and return them via function's window.open()


Hope this clear things up a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What did you say is very strange. I don't know why your links are not working in browser but here is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.links').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(this).attr("target");

    window.open(href, target);

  });
});
```

Comment: thanks mate, I know, added this http://0.s3.envato.com/files/19640971/index.html and modified it, next thing I know, all <a href="www.something.com"> within it not working.