# overriding window.open stops href to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, window.open

I have a single code base which works for mobile and desktop.
In desktop every link should open in new tab and in mobile every link should open in same tab.
To do this i override the window.open method.

```
function targetWindow(name) {
    if(isMobile()){
        return '_self';
    }
    return name;
}

function isMobile() {
    var fnIsIpadNative = window['isMobileNative'];
    return fnIsIpadNative !== undefined && fnIsIpadNative();
}

window.open = function (open) {
    return function (url, name, features) {
        name = targetWindow(name);
        return open.call(window, url, name, features);
    };
}(window.open);
```

I dont know why this code stops href to work.

Comment: There is a hack to make href work http://stackoverflow.com/a/11858814/988864. But i want to know why href stopped working